# Most precise website to estimate gas price for volatile days

Tags: gas-price

I am trying to understand which website is the best way to estimate the gasprice for volatile days. There are some sites but they do not work out so well on a volatile day like today. 
I compared and tested today:

- Metamask browser extension
- Ethgasstation https://ethgasstation.info/(standard fee) which should execute <5min (which it does not)
- ETHGastracker: https://etherscan.io/gasTracker

All have VERY different values. I think for actual transaction execution Ethgasstation is the worst. An transaction in typed in with the Estimated fee for standard (which should execute in under 5min): Is now pending for exactly 20min. For me it is no suprise since ETHGasstation is calculating the average over 1500 blocks (according to site) which is of course a useless number if you have a volatile day. Which site is best for volatile days according to practical experience? If no practical experience is there, for an approximation it would be a page that uses MUCH schorter timeframes like last block, last 2 blocks etc.

Thanks!

Comment: The thing is the better way to calculate prices is not already mined blocks but pending transactions. In my case I use at least two of them and I adjust accordingly to my specific need.

Comment: @Ismael: thats something i played with too a little. Could explain more how exactly you do it? Maybe that is the solution.

Comment: You will be kindof simulating a miner behavior, ie sort pending transaction by gas price and gas limit and calculate how much gas price you have to set for your transaction to be mined in a N blocks.

Answer (score 0):

These are the numbers that these APIs are returning right now... 2 years later, still seems pretty bad.
[image]

Blocknative have a [gas estimator api](https://www.blocknative.com/gas-estimator) which I believe actually listens for mempool transactions and does predictive analysis. But I think it requires a paid plan.